# Compilar sin tener Visual Studio instalado

Tags: visual-studio

¿Se puede compilar sin tener instalado Visual Studio? ¿Existe alguna herramienta portable para utilizar en ordenadores sin VS? He leido sobre la existencia de los VS Build Tools, pero no encuentro donde descargarlo.

Aquí no hay enlace de descarga --> [Visual Studio Build Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=40760)

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: como que no hay enlace de descarga? y el boton rojo que dice "Descargar" (el que esta a la derecha del combo de idioma) que seria

Comment: ¿Que es exactamente lo que quieres compilar? ¿Podrías dar mas detalles? ¿Quizás lo quieres para un servidor de build?

Comment: Un IDE es básicamente un editor de texto glorificado. La compilación misma la hace una aplicación de línea de comando (gcc o similar en el caso de C\C++). La IDE se encarga de los detalles de como llamar a *gcc*, recuperar el listado de errores y presentartelo en un formato conveniente.  Puedes tener múltiples IDE instaladas (VS, Netbeans, PyCharm, etc...) y todas llamaran al mismo compilador por debajo. Puedes crear tu programa usando Notepad si lo deseas, y llamar a *gcc* desde línea de comandos y obtener un ejecutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrias compilar por linea de comando

[Command-line Building With csc.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

es lo que usa `MsBuild`

Tambien podrias evaluar

[The Microsoft Build Engine](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild)

creo que se adecua a lo que planteas

> The Microsoft Build Engine is a platform for building applications. This engine, which is also known as MSBuild, provides an XML schema for a project file that controls how the build platform processes and builds software. Visual Studio uses MSBuild, but MSBuild does not depend on Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

**MSBuild** es una herramienta de construcción que ayuda a automatizar el proceso de creación de un producto de software, incluyendo la compilación del código fuente. Con MSBuild, es posible la construcción de proyectos de Visual Studio y soluciones sin el IDE de Visual Studio instalado. MSBuild actualmente está disponible sin costo.

Yo utilice esta version: [Microsoft Build Tools 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True)

Aqui está la documentacion de la linea de comandos:
[Referencia de la línea de comandos de MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/ms164311.aspx)

En mi caso generé un archivo de proyecto msbuild y lo invoco de la siguiente manera por linea de comnados:

> ```
> MSBuild.exe Proyecto.msbuild /t:Limpiar;Compilar;Test;Comprimir /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 /p:DebugSymbols=false /p:DebugType=None
> ```